# Sort a two-dimensional array by letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, jscript

I want to sort a two-dimensional array with numbers and letters. But not with Javascript rather JScript. (native Microsoft JS engine named 'JScript' (used in Windows Scripting and Internet Explorer) which means we're not actually using JavaScript at all when we develop in IRPA! I'm still going to refer to it as JavaScript because JScript is based on JavaScript (actually called Ecmascript another common problem that I don't help by using them interchangeably)

```
var arr = [
  ['D1-45-32', 'Sneaker'],
  ['11-12-54', 'Ball'],
  ['34-56-12', 'House'],
  ['Y5-78-89', 'Coke'],
  ['11-11-11', 'Ball_1']
];
```

I want to sort it into this order:

```
[
  ['11-11-11', 'Ball_1'],
  ['11-12-54', 'Ball'],
  ['34-56-12', 'House'],
  ['D1-45-32', 'Sneaker'],
  ['Y5-78-89', 'Coke']
]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return /[A-Za-z]/.test(a) - /[A-Za-z]/.test(b) || a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0)
});
console.log(arr);
```

Is there any option to solve the problem with an easy loop?
Thanks

Comment: `arr.sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))`

Comment: `arr` is an array or arrays. `/[A-Za-z]/.test(a)` and `a.charCodeAt(0)` doesn't make sense. Please explain what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to lexicographically sort the arrays by the first element?

Comment: Can you please explain in words what order you want to put the elements in?  Looking only at the expected results, it just looks like you want to sort the outermost array and put its elements (which are arrays) into order based on the first string of those arrays. Do you need to break ties by looking at the second element or anything like that?

Comment: I forgot to add [0] but I have the same problem.

Comment: @Rob98  Have you tried my suggestion?, if your doing this on JScript I've a feeling it maybe doesn't support arrow functions.  So -> `arr.sort(function (a,b) { return a[0].localeCompare(b[0])})` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I fixed that for you:

```
var arr = [['D1-45-32','Sneaker'],['11-12-54','Ball'],['34-56-12','House'],['Y5-78-89','Coke'],['11-11-11','Ball_1']];

arr.sort((a,b)=>{
   if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
    })
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: **Beware**: when you write `a < b`, and  `a` and `b` are arrays, that the arrays will be converted to strings to be compared. An array is converted to string by the rules of [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).  e.g. the array `['D1-45-32','Sneaker']` is converted to the string `D1-45-32,Sneaker` before being compared with any other element in that array.

Comment: The problem is I need JScript and this Code is not working on JScript. (native Microsoft JS engine named 'JScript' (used in Windows Scripting and Internet Explorer) which means we're not actually using JavaScript at all when we develop in IRPA! I'm still going to refer to it as JavaScript because JScript is based on JavaScript (actually called Ecmascript another common problem that I don't help by using them interchangeably).

Comment: sorry i dont know much about JScript.